# CSS of Tabs in a TabPanel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have been messing for the past 2 hours to find how to change the color of the icons and their respective 'label'.

I want to set it to white,

I tried to find a SCSS variable, could not.
I tried to add a css class by various way, none worked.

Would someone have a working exemple ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following css will do the trick

**CSS**

```
    .x-tabbar-dark .x-tab {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    // Here change the style of active tab if you need to
    .x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active .x-button-icon {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab .x-button-icon  {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    }
```

***UPDATE***

**app.scss**

```
// The following two lines import the default Sencha Touch theme. If you are building
// a new theme, remove them and the add your own CSS on top of the base CSS (which
// is already included in your app.json file).
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

// Custom code goes here..

// Examples of using the icon mixin:
// @include icon('user');

.x-tabbar-dark .x-tab {
    color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 .x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active .x-button-icon {
     background-image: none;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

 .x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab .x-button-icon  {
     background-image: none;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>moneyManager</title>
    <style type="text/css">
         /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #1985D0
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -15px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator > * {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            margin: 0 5px;
            width: 30px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
            0% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
            50% {
                opacity: 0
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those css classes are meant to replace the old one? If so where should I put that code? Else which CLS property should I set to those classes?

Comment: Yes it will replace default style and put that code in css file and include that in your html file or if you already created css file for your project then put that code in there.

Comment: Good, just to be sure I understood correctly. If I were to declare those classes in one of my own css ressources, it would automaticly overide the one from the sencha framework? No need to mess with everything?  Are you a magician?

Comment: Yes it will override, ok if there is a another to do this then that  must be using SCSS.. let me check

Comment: You can use [sencha-tabbar-ui mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Bar-css_mixin-sencha-tabbar-ui) to style tabBar but i think you can't change color of icons and label with that

Comment: I don't think you can find another way without overriding css, if you did then post that here.. best of luck

Comment: Ill try your way and post the result, but to me it seems promising!

Comment: Sadly it did not work :( none of the override had any effect on anything.  I tried putting these before the import or after the imports in app.scss and compiled to css right after :(

Comment: Its working for me.. i did test and posted my app.scss code.. see update

Comment: Ill try again and keep your posted

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Your code is the only part of my App.scss that does not modify the display. Could you post your Index/App.html and tell me how you 'previewed' this code to work?

Comment: I posted index.html. It's nothing but default index.html you get when you generate application using sencha Cmd and i added style in app.scss and complied scss code.. thats it

Comment: I found the problem, your code is for tabbar DARK-UI, I was using a LightUi. Thanks alot!! 

BTW The active classes do not seem to work correctly :S

Comment: @Fawar oh i missed and happy that you found the problem.